# clickhouse gives "create user" as syntax error

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

I have enabled access_management also but when I try show users or create user this is how I'm getting.

```
3e6af090665c :) show users;

Syntax error: failed at position 6:

show users;

Expected one of: CREATE, TABLES, DICTIONARIES, PROCESSLIST
```

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: which version of Clickhouse do you use?

Comment: This command available from version [20.5.2.7](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2020/#clickhouse-release-v20-5-2-7-stable-2020-07-02).